# Java: Como faço para armazenar um vetor em outro vetor e usando biblioteca Math

Tags: java, array

minha dúvida é o seguinte, eu tenho que ler 20 números inteiros em um vetor e depois tenho que calcular o quadrado desse vetor e armazenar em um outro e depois exibir os dois.

Só que na hora de fazer o quadrado eu uso uma biblioteca do java que é a Math
o código tá assim na hora de fazer o calculo:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exercicio01Lista { 
   public static void main(String[] args) { 
      int [] num = new int[5]; 
      int [] num2 = new int[5]; 
      Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in); 
      for (int c = 0; c<num.length; c++) { 
         System.out.println("Numero: "); 
         num[c] = entrada.nextInt(); 
      } 
      for (int i = 0; i<num2.length; i++) { 
         num2[i] = Math.sqrt(num[c]); 
      } 
   } 
}
```

só que tá dando erro.

Comment: Essa variável c seria um contador? as matrizes num e num2 tem o mesmo tamanho? Poste mais linhas de código! Qual erro acontece?

Comment: A variavel c é o contador do primeiro vetor, elas tem o mesmo tamanho.
o código:
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exercicio01Lista {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] num = new int[5];
        int [] num2 = new int[5];
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        for (int c = 0; c<num.length; c++){
            System.out.println("Numero: ");
            num[c] = entrada.nextInt();
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i<num2.length; i++){
            num2[i] = Math.sqrt(num[c]);
        }
    }
    
}

Comment: Então tire esse contador que não é necessário. Coloque num[i] no lugar.

Comment: coloquei o i no lugar do num[i] e nao deu certo ainda, o erro é esse aqui:

Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
 at exercicio01lista.Exercicio01Lista.main(Exercicio01Lista.java:15)
C:\Users\Bruno\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
FALHA NA CONSTRUÇÃO (tempo total: 9 segundos)

Comment: Sem saber quais são os números, qual o tamanho de cada vetor e qual o erro que está ocorrendo, não temos como adivinhar. Sugiro que leia a página [ask], como montar um [mcve] e o [Manual de como não fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5484/112052). Em seguida, clique em **[edit]** e adicione as informações faltantes, pois só com esse código e sem saber qual é o erro, não temos como ajudar. Outra coisa, o `sqrt` retorna a raiz quadrada. Se quiser o quadrado, use `Math.pow(valor, 2)` (ou só multiplique o valor por ele mesmo)

Comment: Use o link **[edit]** para colocar essas informações na pergunta, fica mais legível do que nos comentários

Comment: A mensagem de erro menciona `Scanner.nextInt`, e se deu erro nele é porque ele esperava um número mas foi fornecido outra coisa. Favor colocar o código que tem o `Scanner` e os dados que ele está lendo

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer um for que percorre seu array e armazena n² no array novo assim:

```
for (int i = 0; i<arrayValores.length, i++){
   int arrayQuadrado[i] = pow(arrayValores[i],2);
}
```

Comment: Faltou o `Math.` antes do `pow`. Além disso, `Math.pow` retorna `double`.

Answer (score 0):

A varável **c** só é visível no primeiro for, mas como os arrays tem o mesmo tamanho você pode usar a variável **i** para os dois arrays.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] num = new int[5];
        int[] num2 = new int[5];

        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

        for (int c = 0; c < num.length; c++) {
            System.out.println("Numero: ");
            num[c] = entrada.nextInt();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < num2.length; i++) {
            num2[i] = (int) Math.pow(num[i], 2);
        }

        entrada.close();
    }
```

Comment: Agora eu entendi, eu tava colocando o int antes do num2[i] e não depois.
muito obrigado!
aliás já deixo aqui meu obrigado a todos

Comment: `entrada.close();` 

Comment: Alguma dúvida sobre essa linha?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14142853/540552

Comment: Teste o código. Dessa forma não importa se o fluxo de entra for fechado. Está sendo fechado no final da aplicação.

Comment: Me explique qual é a finalidade de fechar-se o `System.in`? Pois é isso que vai acontecer ao fechar-se o `Scanner`.

Comment: Se ele fechar essa entrada de fluxo em qualquer outro lugar, seja em outro método ou classe, terá uma exception, java.util.NoSuchElementException, ao tentar usar a variável entrada no método main, pois o System.in estará fechado. Mas esse não é o caso.

Answer (score 0):

Usando Java 8+, dá para gerar o array com os quadrados em uma só linha. Supondo que o seu array seja a variável `numeros`, então, você pode fazer isso:

```
int[] quadrados = IntStream.of(numeros).map(x -> x * x).toArray();
```

Para ler os 20 números, também dá para fazer com duas linhas:

```
Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
int[] numeros = IntStream.generate(entrada::nextInt).limit(20).toArray();
```

Para exibir o array, dá para fazer em uma linha também:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(quadrados));
```

Eis o código completo resultante. Observe que ele é bem simples, só precisa de 5 linhas entre o `{` e o `}` do método `main`:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

class Teste {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] numeros = IntStream.generate(entrada::nextInt).limit(20).toArray();
        int[] quadrados = IntStream.of(numeros).map(x -> x * x).toArray();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numeros));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(quadrados));
    }
}
```

Dada essa entrada:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

É produzida essa saída:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100, 121, 144, 169, 196, 225, 256, 289, 324, 361, 400]
```

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/BtirYk)

Ah, `Math.sqrt(...)` é para calcular a raiz quadrada. Para calcular o quadrado, a forma mais simples é multiplicar cada elemento por ele mesmo tal como no código acima. Observe que o código para criar o array com os quadrados funciona qualquer que seja o tamanho do array original.

Se quiser que uma mensagem apareça para pedir o número, pode fazer algo assim:

```
int[] numeros = IntStream.generate(() -> {
    System.out.println("Digite um número: ");
    return entrada.nextInt();
}).limit(20).toArray();
```

Comment: É importante fechar o escaneamento de leitura. Ou você pode usar entrada.close() ou try with resources do java. E para ser mais intuitivo você precisa pedir para o usuário inserir algo. Uma mensagem como System.out.println("Informe um numero: ");

Comment: @AntonioSantos Sobre o `Scanner`, não: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14142853/540552 - Sobre a mensagem, o autor da pergunta não colocou nada disso na pergunta dele.

Comment: O autor da mensagem  não usa Stream API. A dúvida está no uso do for. Ele precisa entender o uso do for antes de partir para algo como Stream API. É bom saber as formas mas se o passo anterior for compreendido e o passo seguinte for explicado.

Comment: @AntonioSantos Pelo que vejo no primeiro parágrafo da pergunta, ele pediu como criar um vetor com base em outro vetor, ele não disse que tinha que ser com `for`. Ele apenas tentou fazer isso com um `for` usando o `Math.sqrt`.

Comment: E ele precisa saber onde está o erro, com base no código que ele está usando, mesmo sendo importante saber sobre o uso da API Stream.

Answer (score -3):

troca int por double.

int [] num = new int[5];
double [] num2 = new double[5];

```
     Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in); 
     
      for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) { 
         System.out.println("Numero: "); 
         num[i] = entrada.nextInt(); 
      } 
      for (int i = 0; i<num2.length; i++) { 
         num2[i] = Math.sqrt(num[i]); 
      } 
      
      for (int i = 0; i<num2.length; i++) { 
          System.out.println("A raiz quadrada do número "+num[i]+" é "+num2[i]);
      }
```